# How to schedule function to run at fix point of time?

Tags: python-3.x, time, schedule

Is there any python library that can schedule a function(task) at fix point of time?

For example:

> Every 5 mins: runs at xx:00, xx:05, xx:10 ...
>
> Every 30 mins: runs at xx:00, xx:30 ...
>
> Every 1 hours: runs at 00:00, 01:00, 02:00 ...

If I have to implement myself, is there any convenient utils that can calculates how many seconds I have to sleep before the time point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python have the library called *schedule* which helps to schedule the job or function at scheduled time.

install using

> pip install schedule

here is jupyter notebook python script which will demonstrate the example of schedule

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print('I am working as scheduler....!')

def lunch_job():
    print("Take lunch break, time is : 2.30 PM")

def screen_break_job():
    print("Please take a small break, its been an hour seated")


schedule.every(1).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().hour.do(screen_break_job)
schedule.every().day.at("14:30").do(lunch_job)
schedule.every().monday.do(job)
schedule.every().wednesday.at("13:15").do(job)
schedule.every().minute.at(":17").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

For more details, refer [schedule](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/)

Answer (score 0):

There is [python-crontab](https://pypi.org/project/python-crontab/) which is useful if your on a linux machine, and in case you are on a windows machine you might want to use the [Task Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page),
Also you might want to use some task runner like [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).