# Better way to execute code at a specific time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I need to execute code at exact time, for example `10:00:00.000`.

```
while True:
    now = datetime.utcnow()

    if now.hour == 10 and now.minute == 0 and now.second == 0:
        #execute code here
    time.sleep(1)
```

So far it seems to work but if I launch the code for example one hour before launch I feel like there is a lag in the execution?

Is this the best to achieve what I want?

Comment: You can use the schedule library. For this see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54510910/how-to-schedule-python-function-at-fix-point-of-time/54511001)
.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `datetime` and `threading.Timer`:

```
from datetime import datetime, time
from threading import Timer


def do_the_thing():
    print("execute code here")


Timer(
    (datetime.combine(
        datetime.today(), time(10, 0, 0)
    ) - datetime.now()).total_seconds(),
    do_the_thing
).start()
```

Since `Timer` runs in a background thread, your script can go on to do other things immediately, and `do_the_thing` will get called as soon as the timer is up.

Answer (score 0):

Simply sleep for the total amount of time wanted:

```py
target_date = datetime(day=12, month=12, year=2021, hour=10)
time.sleep((target_date - datetime.now()).total_seconds())
```